# Deleting files inside the folder from specific date using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

My folder structure looks like this:

```
AK_Data |--->2020-01-22-------|----->a.txt
        |                     |----->b.txt
        |                     |------>c.tf.err  
        |
        |--->2021-01-15-------|----->d.txt
        |                     |----->b.txt
        |                     |------>x.tf.err
        | 
        |--->2022-01-08-------|----->dv.txt
        |                     |----->pq.bat
        |
        |--->2022-05-08-------|----->xyz.pdf
```

`AK_Data` is the first folder which consists of multiple `subfolders` like `(2020-01-22,2021-01-15.....)` and these each subfolders contains `1000` of their different format files.

I need to go into each folder and delete all the files except those files having `".tf.err"` in their names. I have used `$specificdate='2022-01-01'` means the files of the folder less than `2022-01-01` only needs to be deleted. So my expected output is:

```
AK_Data |--->2020-01-22-------|------>c.tf.err 
        |                     
        |                      
        |
        |--->2021-01-15-------|------>x.tf.err
        |                     
        |                     
        | 
        |--->2022-01-08-------|----->dv.txt  (this folder will be untouched since>2022-01-01)
        |                     |----->pq.bat
        |
        |--->2022-05-08-------|----->xyz.pdf (this folder will be untouched since>2022-01-01)
```

I only need to delete the files inside the folder, not the folder.

The powershell I used for this is:

```
cls
$specificdate='2022-01-01'
$destination = 'Y:\Data\Retail\ABC\Development\ak\AK_Data'
$files = Get-ChildItem $destination

$exte='\.(bz2)|(.bat)|(.err)|(~)'
   
foreach ($f in $files){
$outfile = $f.FullName -notmatch $exte
if ($outfile){
if ($f.Name -lt $specificdate){
$allfiles=Get-ChildItem $f.FullName -Exclude *.tf.err* -Name | remove-item -whatif

}
}
}
```

It is not deleting the files.

Comment: You are using the `-WhatIf` switch. That means nothing gets deleted, only in the console you can see what _would be_ removed. Is that info correct? then just remove the `-WhatIf` switch and run again. If not, please tell us what problems you have with your code. BTW testing `if ($f.Name -lt $specificdate)` is very tricky and you should actually test [datetime] objects, not strings

Comment: i searched on SO and there someone was using -WhatIf but removing it also it didnt worked. if ($f.Name -lt $specificdate) It listed all the folders less than those dates. My code is not deleting the files inside the subfolders

Comment: Get-ChildItem $f.FullName is printing all the files inside the subfolders but it is not being deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by first iterating the source folder path for directories with a name that can be converted to a datetime less than the datetime in variabe `$specificDate`.

Then use `Get-ChildItem` again inside these folders to find and remove files that do not have `.tf.err` in their name:

```
$specificdate = [datetime]::ParseExact('2022-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
$sourceFolder = 'Y:\Data\Retail\ABC\Development\ak\AK_Data\*'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Directory | 
Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Name,'yyyy-MM-dd', $null) -lt $specificdate } |
ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Removing files from folder $($_.Name).."
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike '*.tf.err*' } |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
}
```

Again here, I added the `-WhatIf` switch so you can first see what *WOULD* happen.
If you're OK with that, remove `-WhatIf` and run the code again to actually delete the files